# Membrr - Credit Card Number not required?

Tags: membrr

I have a billing form for plans/subscriptions that are not free.

However, when trying to submit the form with empty credit card number, it processes the form as valid and subscribes the user.

Is this the default behaviour? If not, are there options to prevent this? Or do I need to implement my own hook for it?

Comment: I think its related with some gateways doesn't requiere CC info recollected before the actual payment (usually for offsite payments). What gateway are you using? Also check http://help.electricfunction.com/ I remember seeing very similar question already

Comment: @DavorPeic Ok. Please put your comment as an answer so I can resolve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its related with some gateways doesn't requiere CC info recollected before the actual payment (usually for offsite payments). What gateway are you using? Also check help.electricfunction.com I remember seeing very similar question already

Answer (score 2):

Davor is right, it looks like [this question](http://help.electricfunction.com/discussions/membrr-for-ee/12487-renewal-doesnt-require-cc-info) is very similar. It notes a bug and an update to eWay and Stripe payment gateway code for Membrr.

That said, you might also consider using some client side form validation to avoid the form being submitted at all without the CC# field being validated. On our site we use the [jQuery validation plug-in](http://jqueryvalidation.org). If you want to see it in action on our site you can [see it here](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/store/order/1001)